# How to cast numbers (like int) to "Number"?

Tags: java, casting, numbers

This could be basic question but I could not find something useful.

Question is: How to convert `double` or `int` value to `Number` type ( to be more specific `oracle.jbo.domain.Number`)

I tried the following:

**for integer values**

```
         int i=9;
         Integer y=new Integer(i);
         oracle.jbo.domain.Number num=(oracle.jbo.domain.Number)y;
```

**for float values**

```
         double i=9.5;
         Double y=new Double(i);
         oracle.jbo.domain.Number num=(oracle.jbo.domain.Number)y;
```

But I always get incompatible types error in both cases:

```
Type 'oracle.jbo.domain.Number' incompatible with 'java.lang.Integer'
```

and

```
Type 'oracle.jbo.domain.Number' incompatible with 'java.lang.Double'
```

if the conversion did not work, then how to simply create `Number` object in java

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do not need to cast it. just use constructor of [Number](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/apirefs.1111/e10655/oracle/jbo/domain/Number.html#Number%28int%29) class.

```
int value = 5;
oracle.jbo.domain.Number num = new oracle.jbo.domain.Number(value);
```

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b14023/oracle/jbo/domain/Number.html). You can construct new `Number` objects like so:

```
Number dNumber = new Number(9.5);
Number iNumber = new Number(9);
```

Comment: Today the class ```Number``` is abstract. Doesn't can be instantiated.

Comment: @rplaurindo Any other way to do it?