# Difference of oracle.jbo.domain.Number and java.lang.Number

Tags: java, oracle, jdeveloper

I'm re-learning Java to work on an OAF (Oracle Application Framework) Page and I'm getting an error below due to a line in my code:

**Code Line**

`Number attrValue = (Number)currRow.getAttribute("IctTrxHdrId");`

**Error Message**

> oracle.apps.fnd.framework.OAException: java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.jbo.domain.Number

I was able to resolve this taking the advice from a post in [Oracle Forums](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2316599?start=0) that i should import `oracle.jbo.domain.Number` so that `attrValue` will use the `oracle.jbo.domain.Number` class instead of `java.lang.Number`.

Also read from [another post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23320267/how-to-cast-numbers-like-int-to-number/23320280#23320280) that I can use the below syntax to use `oracle.jbo.domain.Number`:

`oracle.jbo.domain.Number attrValue = (oracle.jbo.domain.Number) currRow.getAttribute("IctTrxHdrId");`

I'm curious, What's the difference between the two classes?

Comment: They're two different classes with the same name.

Comment: Have you checked their source codes? Which differences do you see there? And maybe also read the JavaDoc: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/apirefs.1111/e10655/oracle/jbo/domain/Number.html

Answer (score 0):

The class [`oracle.jbo.domain.Number`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16764_01/apirefs.1111/e10655/oracle/jbo/domain/Number.html) is a wrapper around the class [`java.lang.Number`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html).

The goal is to have a domain object in the sense of the [Oracle Fusion Middleware](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/fusion-middleware/overview/index.html).

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E51625_01/apirefs.1111/e10655/oracle/jbo/domain/package-summary.html):

> The oracle.jbo.domain.* classes, also known as the "JBO Generic Domains", provide lightweight wrappers for the native Java data types, such as java.lang.Number and java.sql.Date. These wrappers allow the native Java datatypes to be represented as domain objects. A domain is a class for scalar data values that can be accessed in a tier-independent manner, and that has no inherent implication on mappability to database columns.